# Animate background-color of html5 progress element

Tags: jquery, css, html, progress-bar

I am working on an image up-loader. I don't have any problems with updating the progress element value during the upload. Although after the upload is finish I would like to change the background color of the element with an animation.

In my jQuery I give the element a different class and:

```
$(newImageElement).find('.list-item__image-holder 
.progressBar').addClass('progressBar-green');
```

And this is my css:

```
.list-item__image-holder .progressBar-green[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
-webkit-animation: progressBarAnimation 3s ease-in;
animation: progressBarAnimation 3s ease-in;
}


@keyframes progressBarAnimation {
  0% {
      background-color: #f96332;
  }
  100% {
      background-color: #5cb860;
 }
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Once the class is added you want the color to change via animation? I think you'll be able to do what you want VIA CSS transitions.

Comment: @Gazzasa Yes it was as simple as using CSS Transition. Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help :). I'll post the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using CSS Transitions. Works great for animations and no JS required.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

```
.list-item__image-holder .progressBar {
    background-color: #f96332;
    transition: background-color ease-in 1s;
}

.list-item__image-holder .progressBar.progressBar-green {
    background-color: #5cb860;
}
```

made an example but used `:hover` instead of `.addClass()`

https://jsfiddle.net/zk0Lg345/